# SSRS Reports not loading after making RDLC format conversion for VS 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a fairly large application that we have been using VS 2008 for including Report Viewer 2008. Lately we have made the hop and decided to migrate to VS 2015, however in doing so VS 2015 requires all .RDLC templates be converted to the latest format to use the designer. After doing so I am indeed able to open the reports in the designer and they visually appear to have ported fine however they fail to load in the compiled application all together. I receive the following error

> An error occurred during local report processing.

I understand this is a pretty generic error so I know it's not much help. Additionally all reports work fine prior to the conversion in the compiled application I simply can't open them in the designer. I have attempted to use a newer version of report viewer and it did fix this specific issue and reports loaded however it introduced other issues as well as a deployment headache, so ideally this would be possible with SSRS 2008.

Does anyone have any idea what the conversion might be doing to make reports specifically not load with ReportViewer 2008? Are the converted templates incompatible?

Thank you ahead of time for any help.

Comment: Whenever I have seen this error, it usually ends up being a permissions thing. Something like I forgot to update a connection with the username/password and save it. I can see that being necessary after a conversion. Have you tried that?

Comment: All of my connections are up to date. I appreciate the reply though.

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication or SQL authentication to connect for data? If Windows, then change the connection(s) to use SQL authentication and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: this is a generic error in rdlc; try catching the `Exception` and give a look at the various levels of `InnerException` (i.e.: `ex.Message`, `ex.InnerException.Message`, `ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message` and so on) to provide us more information.